# CSS content is wrapping rather than expanding the div

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have this table:

```
<div class="info" id="item">
<div id="item_container">
    <div id="item" style="color: rgb(255,255,255); color: rgba(255,255,255,255); margin: 0 auto; width: auto; display:table; padding:3px; background: rgb(0,0,0); background: rgba(0,0,0,255);">
        <div id="table_row" style="display:table-row; width: auto;">
            <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-column; width:auto; float:left;">40</div>
            <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-column; width:auto; float:left;">40</div>
            <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-column; width:auto; float:left;">40</div>
            <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-column; width:auto; float:left;">40</div>
            <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-column; width:auto; float:left;">40</div>
            <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-column; width:auto; float:left;">40</div>
            <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-column; width:auto; float:left;">40</div>
            <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-column; width:auto; float:left;">40</div>
            <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-column; width:auto; float:left;">40</div>
            <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-column; width:auto; float:left;">40</div>
            <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-column; width:auto; float:left;">40</div>
            <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-column; width:auto; float:left;">40</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The full table is on the fiddle below and explains things a bit better.
http://jsfiddle.net/k2mqB/12/

Some of the content is dynamically created and that is why you see some inline styling.

Now I know the first thing people might get hung up on is why I'm using divs to create a table. Well the problem I had was I needed a table but I didn't want the columns to line up so column 2 for all the rows is in the same place.

For example see below and in the fiddle, even if the cells differ in width from row to row notice that it still is rectangle in shape like a table as it expands to the furthest value (cheer) and doesn't end up looking like a few rows of lego. I could not figure out a way to do that with a table or a div but with both combined I could. It might not be true and there might be a way to do it better than this but I couldn't find it. This combination of divs styled as tables worked well for me.

```
|--------|---------|----------|
| test   | happy days yep|----|
| another| test | is this|one   |
|this is the final|countdown|cheer|
|--------|---------|----------|---|
```

It might not be the perfect solution but CSS isn't my strong point. I find that I constantly end up adding things to control it and I get to the point I have so much stuff they interfere with each other and I'm not sure which to remove and which to add.

So if you look at my fiddle you will notice that the vertical scroll is working. But notice I have 12 cells on each row yet it wraps after 6 presumably cause of the width. I need to conserve the width on the outer column so what I want to do is have it do horizontal scroll too.

The reason is I have a 3 column layout on my site, this container is one of the 3, if it expands the height or width then it will move the columns out of order because one is higher or too wide.

Here is the CSS but that's also on the fiddle:

```
#item{
overflow:auto;
width:220px;
height:170px;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 92%;
background-color: #E6E4E4;
}

.info{
    padding:0px;
}

div{
    display: block;   
}

#item-container{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 220px;
    max-width: 220px;
    height: 170px;
    max-height: 170px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#table-row{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;    
}
```

So a lot of data but my issue is simple, I need to have horizontal scroll so it keeps the dimension of the outer container.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue you're needing help with? It seems like you already know the answer to the issue. The item's width is too small to hold 12 cells so they wrap down to the next line.

Comment: Instead of wrapping i want it to scroll horizontally. btw there was an error in the first bit of code, i changed that now. It had the outer container at 100x100px and that was a mistake, its the same as the inner container 220 x 170px

New fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k2mqB/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ID's are unique, they cannot be used more than once on a page.  Use classes instead.

Second, when you use `float` you take something out of the document flow.  To get the parent to overflow horizontally, you need to remove that.  Then instead of setting your cells to `display: table-column`, use `display: table-cell`.  That should do it.

```
<div class="table_row" style="display:table-row; width: auto;">
  <div class="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:table-cell; width:auto;">40</div>
  ...
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k2mqB/8/)**

Comment: While this works perfect in the demo, once i remove the float:left everything gets messed up. I guess if thats the only option ill need to dig into the css code outside that container, what i showed you in the fiddle was only 1 container which is inside other containers so looks like they are having an effect as your solution clearly works, is there another way to do this without removing float:left?

Comment: What do you mean it gets messed up?  The code you provided looks fine.  We can only offer a solution for the code you give.  It's not the only option, there's one other.  If you use `display: inline-block` you can control the horizontal scroll by specifying `white-space: nowrap` on the parent.  But you'll have to move away from your faux table layout.

Comment: Yes, in the context of what i was asking this was the correct and best solution, it didnt solve my issue but ill dig deeper, knowing how the inner divs should work will help me a lot but i need to see which one of the parent divs is messing things up, appreciate the response

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of using tables for displaying tabluated data.

In your CSS you have a width: 100px defined here;

```
#item{
overflow:auto;
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 92%;
background-color: #E6E4E4;
}
```

You also have an inline style width: auto; which doesn't change anything.

Increase your width to around 200px and you will see that all 12 divs fit on a row.

Cheers,

Darren

Answer (score 0):

**You can't use an ID on a page more than once.**  It's an ID to point to only one element.

Use `class` instead.  Example:

```
<div class="info" id="item">
    <div id="item_container">
        <div id="item" ... >
...
             <div id="cell" ... >
             <div id="cell" ... >
```

In the above, only the first `#item` and first `#cell` will be changed with your CSS.

## [More appropriate CSS/HTML demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cjTtq/)

This demo shows the same page, but with the HTML and CSS using classes instead of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

As first, you should alter your CSS rules:

```
#item {
    overflow: scroll;
    /* ... */
}
```

Then, you should change your HTML code to:

```
<div class="info" id="item">
  <div id="item_container">
    <div id="item" style="color: rgb(255,255,255); color: rgba(255,255,255,255); margin: 0 auto; width: auto; display:table; padding:3px; background: rgb(0,0,0); background: rgba(0,0,0,255);">
      <div id="table_row" style="white-space:nowrap; width: auto;">
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
      </div>


      <div id="table_row" style="white-space:nowrap; width: auto;">
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
      </div>


      <div id="table_row" style="white-space:nowrap; width: auto;">
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
      </div>


      <div id="table_row" style="white-space:nowrap; width: auto;">
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
      </div>


      <div id="table_row" style="white-space:nowrap; width: auto;">
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
      </div>


      <div id="table_row" style="white-space:nowrap; width: auto;">
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
      </div>


      <div id="table_row" style="white-space:nowrap; width: auto;">
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
      </div>


      <div id="table_row" style="white-space:nowrap; width: auto;">
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
        <div id="cell" style="font-size:7px; padding: 0px 2px; display:inline-block;">40</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this way you will achieve what you want to achieve.